# What properties of grass would a plant need to fill the niche of grasses?

Tags: flora, creature-design

What features of grasses would need to exist in a plant for the plant to fill the same niche as grasses in a grassland?

Comment: Last time I checked grass was a plant. I don't understand your question.

Comment: The OP is asking, in a scenario where grass itself does not exist, what must the properties of the replacement plant be, to fulfill the same ecological roles. For example, in the right climate, Kudzu is a very good "grass replacement" plant.

Comment: Lack of branches maybe... I guess hee hee

Comment: Grasses are a latecomer in the vegetable kingdom. The first grasses appeared towards the end of the [Cretaceous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous), and grasslands did not become widespread until the Late [Miocene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Miocene) epoch, well into the [Neogene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neogene) era. Before that, there were only forests and shrublands. As so, the answer is trivially simple: if there were no grasses, grasslands would revert to being forests or shrublands, as they had been for hundreds of millions of years before the rise of grasses.

Comment: @AlexP This question is asking what a plant needs to form a 'grassland', not what would happen without grasses

Comment: A **grass**land is formed by grasses: nothing but grasses can form a grassland. Areas dominated by plants other than grasses have different names -- forest, shrubland, heathland, moorland and so on. Or else, the question must explain what is to be understood by grassland, if not an area of land dominated by grasses. And, on one hand, heaths look pretty grassland-ish to me; on the other hand, the Poaceae are not the only family in the order Poales; rushes (Juncaceae) and sedges (Cyperaceae) come to mind.

Comment: may be helpful. http://www.plantphysiol.org/content/125/3/1198 and https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-earth-040809-152402?journalCode=earth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Rapid growth and spreading.
- Willing to grow in marginal and poor soils.
- Ability to survive grazing, including *really severe* grazing.
- Ability to survive being stepped on by absolutely everything in sight.
- Strong root system for stabilizing soil.
- Ability to either survive fire, or rapidly reseed and regrow after a fire.
- If in a region that experiences frost and snow, it should be able to at least regrow rapidly after a frost, better survive and thrive even after being frozen solid.
- Capable of letting the upper surface "die", to provide reduced water needs and shade/thermal protection in event of drought/water shortage.
- Ideally, should be significantly nutritious to eat, as this invites grazers to trim old growth and fertilize and spread seeds.
- Should *not* grow tall enough for a 'grass' fire to become a 'forest' fire.

Comment: My understanding is that grasses came to dominate because ungulates evolved a new enzyme allowing them to eat woody stems, and grasses grow back from the base, not the bud. Animals ate the brush, and the brush couldn't recover. Grasses could.

Comment: @DWKraus Yep. That's the third point in here. Ability to survive being eaten (because he important bits are down where they are safe). With a root system that does most of the growing effort, does not die of grazing or trampling, and usually survives frost and fire, you have a plant that completely dominates its niche. Hence, the formation of grasslands.